# Semi-exact (complete) match in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to require a complete (though not necessarily exact) match in ElasticSearch?

For instance, if a field has the term `"I am a little teapot short and stout"`,  I would like to match on `" i am a LITTLE TeaPot short and stout! "` but not just `"teapot short and stout"`. I've tried the term filter, but that requires an actual exact match.

Comment: Have you tried setting up custom analyzers, together with a match query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "not necessarily exact" definition refers to uppercase/lowercase letters combination and the punctuation marks (like `!` you have in your example), this would be a solution, not too simple and obvious tough:

**The mapping**:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_keyword_lowercase": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "trim",
            "my_pattern_replace"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_pattern_replace": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "!",
          "replacement":""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_keyword_lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea here is the following:

1. use a `keyword` tokenizer to keep the text as is and not to be split into tokens
2. use the `lowercase` filter to get rid of the mixing uppercase/lowercase characters
3. `trim` filter used to get rid of the trailing and leading whitespaces
4. use a `pattern_replace` filter to get rid of the punctuation. This is like this because a `keyword` tokenizer won't do anything to the characters inside the text. A `standard` analyzer will do this, but the `standard` will, also, split the text whereas you need it as is

And this is **the query** you would use for the mapping above:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": " i am a LITTLE TeaPot short and stout! "
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks for the example.